# Can I make it so that a fanfare plays when my code compiles in Eclipse (Java)?

Tags: eclipse

I always feel so pleased when my code compiles and I've always dreamed of the Final Fantasy VII victory theme or Zelda treasure chest theme playing along with the successful compilation.

I've only been programming for two weeks (unless you include my 8 years of HTML on Neopets).  Please tell me what I need to do to make my dream come true.

**Edit** -- I know that many of you will probably think that this will become annoying after about three compiles, but trust me, it's fine. I've had Captain Falcon shout "YES" at me every time I've received a text for the past year and I still think it's hilarious.

Comment: Continue your work, and you will see that having such thing on your Eclipse will be really annoying :)

Comment: Don't worry - in another two weeks you'll be sick of hearing the fanfare and want to turn it off.

Comment: Who is marking this as off-topic? The FAQ specifically says questions about software tools used by programmers are ON TOPIC!

Comment: You would have to get the Eclipse team to either include a hook on the compiler that calls out to the OS, or you would have to edit the code to play the song, or you would need to create a wrapper to the java compiler to play the song if you wanted ...

Comment: ouch! my office will start sounding like Game-Zone with people setting up successful compilation sounds. And, I am sure some of them will set it to a vulgar one!

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap javac then redirect eclipse to use the wrapper? Is it easy to tell eclipse to use a different executable, or would that be a pain?

Comment: @Rosarch ~ I would think using a bash script and path would be sufficient on most linux systems.

Comment: @drachenstern, @Rosarch : Eclipse uses its own java compiler, which is afaik in-process pure java.

Comment: @ThomasDufour ~ So it shows that I don't know Eclipse. But for pure java compiles that should work.

Comment: I voted to move this question to programmers.stackexchange.com, but for some reason it hasn’t been moved. Not my fault! Therefore, I’m voting to reopen...

Comment: Eclipse syntax check your code continuously and compiles it every time you save the file in the editor.  Do you _really_ want a sound everytime you save a file?

Comment: @Dan Grossman - while some might consider this question to be a little _too localized_, it is most decidedly _on topic_ according to the FAQ. I've re-opened it.

Comment: "8 years of HTML on Neopets" I picked up HTML from Neopets more than half my life ago (I'm currently 19).

Comment: A lot of you are assuming the OPer has Project→Build Automatically turned on. That option is there for a reason: very large projects slow Eclipse right down if that option is turned on. Those same large projects take a long time to compile, so it's nice to have a sound effect indicate when compiling has finished, so developers know when it's time to stop <s>surfing the web</s> reviewing corporate policy. I've included such sound effects in Ant/Maven scripts in the past, but hope for a simple Eclipse feature is what brought me to this question. Ah well.

Answer (score 13):

I am not aware of a "native" way of having a music played after a successful build. However, if I *really* need to have that (you have to consider that after some work, it will be really annoying), I would consider the following ideas:

1: Trying to find a builder (`Project properties > Builders`) that allows specific task after the compilation of a project;

2: Use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to compile your project. Add a task, for example [sound](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sound.html) that will play a different song regarding the result of the build:

```
<target name="fun" if="fun" unless="fun.done">
  <sound>
    <success source="${user.home}/sounds/bell.wav"/>
    <fail source="${user.home}/sounds/ohno.wav" loops="2"/>
  </sound>
  <property name="fun.done" value="true"/>
</target>
```

3: Use an Continuous Integration server, such as Hudson (oops, Jenkins ;) ) and add [a plugin to play a sound after a build](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hudson+Sounds+plugin).

---

Just a personal note: I think this can be a good idea to have a specific sound / music played after a **failed** build done by a IC server...

Comment: Can I +1 again for the suggestion of a failed tone, that might actually be helpful in some environments :\

Comment: Why would the operators in the data center want to hear when your CI server succeeds with a build?

Comment: BTW, you can easily use the Maven `exec` plugin to do this by binding it to the right part of the lifecycle. Just sayin' (and I think it's a bad idea to do this, so I won't say how).

Comment: @Donal ~ Because CI does not mean datacenter?

Comment: @romaintaz, @drachenstern: You keep your server under the desk? Isn't that a bit of a problem if you accidentally kick the power lead?

Comment: @Donal Not necessarily under my desk, but it can be on the same room. To be honest, I do *not* set such sound configuration on my IC servers, I just said that this can be useful, at least more useful than having this sound played on each successfully compiled project on my Eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that eclipse does not have a real build cycle for java.

- Eclipse works on the abstract syntax tree of your java code
- The editor state is dumped into a .java and .class file on save

So "after compiling" would mean "every file save that doesn't cause the project to contain errors afterwards". I don't think there is an option for that.